# Arcpy : setting DataFrame scale to export map over specific domain

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, scale, png

I am trying to automate the export of a map to png over a given domain (SW and NE coordinates) in ArcPy (ArcMap version 10.7.1). I've searched a bit but fail at setting the correct automatized scale (depending on the image size i give the scale can be way too high or way too small). I am clearly missing something in the process.

Does someone have any suggestion or hint ?

Currently, my script is the following :

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(input_path)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

#Domain X and Y coordinates (domain limits given as floats in meters)
XW = 
XE = 
YS = 
YN = 

#output image size in pixels
x_pix = 4000.0
y_pix = 3000.0
#output image size in cm
x_cm = x_pix/37.7952755906
y_cm = y_pix/37.7952755906

extent = arcpy.Extent(XW,YS,XE,YN)
df.extent = newExtent
df.panToExtent(extent)
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()

#compute appropriate scale
#convert domain width and height to cm (factor 100) and divide by image size in cm
x_scale = 100.0*(XE-XW)/x_cm
y_scale = 100.0*(YN-YS)/y_cm
#select scale to ensure that the desired domain is within the image
df.scale = max(x_scale,y_scale)

#export
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd,output_path,df,x_pix,y_pix,world_file=True)
```

Here are two examples for the same domain :

1- desired domain to export

2- result for 3000 by 2250 pixels

3- result for 8000 by 6000 pixels

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to explain a bit more about your process. What are x_cm and y_cm? Why are you multiplying the x_scale by 100? What version of arcmap are you using? Also, an example image showing what is wrong and illustrating the desired output would help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I added more details as well as examples hoping it makes my problem more comprehensible.

Comment: I think you should be multiplying instead of dividing to calculate x_cm and y_cm

Comment: What i calculate here is the dimensions of the output image so multiplying by 37 would mean that one pixel has a size of 37 cm. From what i found one pixel is about 0.26 mm so 1/37 seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set the extent of the data frame explicitly using:

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
newExtent = df.extent
newExtent.XMin, newExtent.YMin = XW, YS
newExtent.XMax, newExtent.YMax = XE, YN
df.extent = newExtent
```

Details can be found here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm

Approaching it this way should mean that you don’t have to worry about setting the scale. Does that accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: The two setting methods seem to be equivalent as i get exactly the same coordinates when reading `df.extent`. However, I think you're right when telling me i don't have to worry about the scale. I will try to find a new way to get the exact extent (currently there is a margin added to the frame).

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm that this works but per the answer here, try running `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` and `arcpy.RefreshTOC()` right before setting `df.extent = newExtent`, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86486/arcpy-export-unable-to-set-exact-extent-of-dataframe